# Change All table cell margins in a word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am working on a very large word document that provides documentation for a software project I am developing. Somewhere along the line all of my tables lost the cell padding they had when I originally created them. Is there a way to set the cell properties for all of the tables in my document at once or do I need to edit the tables one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of guesswork about what you want and what you have, maybe the following would suit:

Table Tools, Design, Table Styles, Modify Table Style, Format, Table Properties, Cell, Options, Cell Margins.